# receive mail from mailgun: “The page has expired due to inactivity” - Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, csrf, laravel-routing

I want send an email form mailgun to my website (on server with https)

So in web.php I add:

```
Route::post('/text/text1', 'testController@mailgun')->name('mailgun');
```

in this doc: `app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php`

I changed this:

```
protected $except = [
  '/5087643977:AAFxaiDdfhfghyhjsqDZKBTExmDq98/webhook',
  '/test/test1/*'
];
```

and in **session.php**

```
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', true),
```

Now, in mailgun page (https://app.mailgun.com/app/routes)
I test it with this URL:

```
https://www.example.com/test/test1
```

But in mailgun tester, it return 419 error:

> The page has expired due to inactivity.

what is my wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
protected $except = [
    '/test/test1/*'
];
```

The pattern here `/test/test1/*` will not match your request path `/test/test1`, it will only match `/test/test1/*`. You can fix this by changing the pattern:

```
protected $except = [
    '/test/test1'
];
```